# Add next/prev button to text 'slider'

Tags: jquery, navigation

I have the following text 'slider' ( [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/brilliancedisplay/N2ELe/) ) and I would like to add next / prev buttons to it and I don't quite know where to start..

I tried binding `showNextQuote();` to a click function but what it did is show the two quotes simultaneously.

```
<h2 class="quotes">first quote</h2>
<h2 class="quotes">second quote</h2>
```

**Script:**

```
(function() {

    var quotes = $(".quotes");
    var quoteIndex = -1;

    function showNextQuote() {
        ++quoteIndex;
        quotes.eq(quoteIndex % quotes.length)
            .fadeIn(2000)
            .delay(2000)
            .fadeOut(2000, showNextQuote);
    }

    showNextQuote();

})();
```

**PS:
I also tried:**

```
    $('#next').on('click', getNext);
    $('#prev').on('click', getPrev);

function getNext() {
    var $curr = $('.quotes:visible'),
        $next = ($curr.next().length) ? $curr.next() : $('.quotes').first();

    transition($curr, $next);
}

function getPrev() {
    var $curr = $('.quotes:visible'),
        $next = ($curr.prev().length) ? $curr.prev() : $('.quotes').last();
    transition($curr, $next);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to use [.stop()](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) to stop current animation before running new one and passing `1` or `-1` to function:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Regent3000/N2ELe/34/).

HTML:

```
<h2 class="quotes">first quote</h2>
<h2 class="quotes">second quote</h2>
<h2 class="quotes">third quote</h2>
<input id="prev" type="button" value="Prev" />
<input id="next" type="button" value="Next" />
```

JS:

```
$(function()
{
    var quotes = $(".quotes");
    var quoteIndex = -1;

    function showQuote(change)
    {
        quoteIndex += change;
        if (quoteIndex < 0)
        {
            quoteIndex += quotes.length;
        }
        else if (quoteIndex >= quotes.length)
        {
            quoteIndex -= quotes.length;
        }
        quotes.stop(true, true).hide().eq(quoteIndex)
            .fadeIn(2000)
            .delay(2000)
            .fadeOut(2000)
            .queue(function() { showQuote(1); });
    }  
    showQuote(1);

    $('#prev').on('click', function()
    {
        showQuote(-1);
    });

    $('#next').on('click', function()
    {
        showQuote(1);
    });
});
```

Comment: Well this does work in a certain way...I still need to figure out a way to make the prev button

Comment: :)) Well, yours certainly works better (and makes more sense) than my sh***y version :) Thanks, +1 and accepted :D Have a nice day

Comment: @Alin you're welcome. By the way, one of the main ideas is to avoid code duplicating. And one issue that I have seen when was testing the code: if you click button during `.fadeOut()`, both elements are hidden (with buttons moving up) for a second or two. Maybe it is important to you, maybe not.

Comment: It is, that only happens if you click during the fadeOut function, if you hide the quote during the fadeOut function it will take the fadeOut time and place it to the hide function...

Comment: @Alin well, maybe the new (third) solution with `.queue()` is not perfect, but at least it finally works as it is supposed to work.

Comment: Haha :) Well now it's working great :D Thanks once again ! ^^